# Only Email value is showing in database custom newsletter value showing null value in magento how to solve it?

Tags: magento2, php, database

Subscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Newsletter;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Subscriber {
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    Http $request
  ) {
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function aroundSubscribe($subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {
    if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('subscriber_name')) {
      $firstname = $this->getRequest->getPost('subscriber_name');
      print_r($firstname);
      $subject->setCFirstname($firstname);
      $result = $proceed($email);

      try {
        $subject->save();
      }catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

subscribe.phtml

```
<div class="block newsletter">
  <div class="title"><strong><?php echo __('Newsletter') ?></strong></div>
  <div class="content">
    <form class="form subscribe"
    novalidate
    action="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
    method="post"
    data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
    id="newsletter-validate-detail">
    <div class="field firstname">
      <label class="label" for="firstname"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('First Name')) ?></span></label>
      <div class="control">
        <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname"
        placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscriber Name')) ?>"
        data-validate="{required:true}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field newsletter">
      <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:')) ?></span></label>
      <div class="control">
        <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter"
        placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enter your email address')) ?>"
        data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Subscribe')) ?>" type="submit">
        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Subscribe')) ?></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

> if ($this->request->isPost() &&
> $this->request->getPost('subscriber_name'))
> {
>
> $firstname = $this->getRequest->getPost('subscriber_name');

with

> if ($this->request->isPost() &&
> $this->request->getPost('firstname'))
> {
>
> $firstname = $this->getRequest->getPost('firstname');

And then you need to save that like this :

```
$subject->setSubscriberName($firstname);
```

Comment: hey @Dhiren i am getting same issu after chage this

Comment: my email field value is showing in  database but name field value showing null

Comment: is your databae field name is this one? setCFirstname

Comment: database field name is Subscriber_name

Comment: Then you need to save the value like this : $subject->setSubscriberName($firstname);

Comment: i also change setSubscriberName but i also getting same issu null value

Comment: But where you added that fields, and how?

Comment: please help me why i am not getting value in database

Comment: hey i added like this if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('subscriber_name')) {
      $subscriberName = $this->getRequest->getPost('subscriber_name');
      $subject->setSubscriberName($subscriberName)

Comment: in Vendor\Module\Plugin\Newsletter\Subscriber.php

Comment: Hey @Dhiren help me please  how i can solve this issu